# Documentation in C# Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I need to dynamically generate the help for some WEB-API.
The problem is that are dynamic both  in the input parameters that in the structure of output.

See the Example:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("API/Individuals")]
[ActionName("Individuals")]
public HttpResponseMessage Select()
{
     var Params = this.Request.RequestUri.ParseQueryString();
     string UserNameCVT = Code.RemappingUser.Remap(UserName.Name);
     DataSet ds = Models.Individuals.Individuals.SelectDS(UserNameCVT, Params);
     List<Dictionary<string, object>> lDict = DecodeIndividualsFromDS(ds);

     response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, lDict);
     return response;
}
```

By doing this, the API is to decouple that from FE DB below, leaving them free to modify the data structures according to their needs.

Is it possible to generate a complete Help once the structures are defined (without changing the code of the API)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. The key line of code in the XML documentation provider is this (from this [getting started page](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/creating-api-help-pages)):

```
config.SetDocumentationProvider(new XmlDocumentationProvider(
HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/XmlDocument.xml")));
```

As you see, the documentation is read from a file path. If you can dynamically create that file on the start of your application, and then pass in the file path, you are set. (You have to find a way to handle those end points dynamically, but that is not in the scope of this question)

Also, if you need to do more, you can create a custom implementation by [taking the `XmlDocumentationProvider` from Github](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/WebApiHelpPage/Areas/HelpPage/XmlDocumentationProvider.cs) and write your own.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My problem now is how to dynamically create the documentation files. I saw that there are different attributes, but I can not find good documentation/examples.